# How to render pages from external websites on the current webpage?

Tags: iframe, render

I would like to know the different ways to render the content from an external URL after grabbing the corresponding webpage? I heard of iframes. Is it the best way? Or are there other better ways too? P.S., I want to render dynamic stuff like games and other interactive content too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

iframe works good , but still there is sameorigin policy, which prevents you from accessing child content from parent and viceversa, if both are not in the same domain